# Can't to place categories module on product page

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I need to place "Jshopping Categories" module at bottom of the product page.
On main page this module placed at the position 'position-22' .
I tried using this code:

```
$modules =JModuleHelper::getModules('position-22');
foreach ($modules as $module){
   echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
```

but it shows no effect.
And, if I use this code :

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');
$options = array('style' => 'raw');
$dbo = JFactory::getDBO();
$dbo->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__modules WHERE id='91' ");
$module = $dbo->loadObject();
$module->params = "heading=2\nlimit=10";
echo $renderer->render($module, $options);
```

I get only the categories title but no images.

I'm using JoomShopping component in Joomla 3.4.

Also I'm thinking to use "Load module" plugin. But how I can place my custom HTML with "{loadposition position-22}" in my page template?

Comment: If it is in position-22 why are you getting position-10? You will probably be better off at [joomla.se].

Comment: Excuse me, I using  'position-22' . I edited my question

Comment: It transpired, a module was enabled only for selected pages. If it enabled for all pages, a code from a first example works. But in this case a module is displayed on each page(on page with code like above is displayed twice).

Comment: How and where you are going to use {loadposition} method?